# How to get array inside of object?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, fetch

I use react-redux to get my API data and put the data into my `FlatList`. I know i have to put an array into my `FlatList` `data` fuction.

But i don't know how to parse my data...

I try `const movieData = this.props.movieList[0].movie;` is no working.

How do i parse the data if i want to put the `movie` array into my `FlatList` ?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is my API https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=Taipei&theater=Centuryasia

Here is my component `render` function:

```
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    console.log(this.props.movieList[0]);
    const movieData = this.props.movieList[0];

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={movieData}
          renderItem={this.renderItem} 
          numColumns={1}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Here is my console.log
[image]

Comment: Just add `this.props.movieList[0].movie ` to your Flatlist `data`

Comment: I add it , its no working. It will show `BugReporting extraData:`

Comment: Try adding your code [here](https://snack.expo.io)

Comment: Thanks for your help Pritish, i take a reference from @Nirmalsinh answer and figure it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api response will come in array. And Array is having object. You can assess **movie** data as below:

```
 let data = response.data;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 let movie = data[0]['movie'];
 console.log('====================================')
 console.log(JSON.stringify(movie));
```

Here is API call for your url:

```
 const axios = require('axios');
                const apiURL = 'https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=Taipei&theater=Centuryasia';

                axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: apiURL,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'Application/json',
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    const success = response.status;
                    let data = response.data;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                    let movie = data[0]['movie'];
                    console.log('====================================')
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(movie));
                }).catch((error) => {
                    alert(error);
                });
```

Comment: Thank you @Nirmalisinh , i figure it out now. I try to fix it from my reducer parse the responseData like `responseData[0]` then i can get the data by using `const movieData = this.props.movieList.movie;`  Thanks again.

Comment: @徐博俊 Happy to help you